# SCSS Variable to toggle background URL from path to ASSET_URL

Tags: sass, shopify, liquid

Is this even possible? Basically I have my static HTML templates which use image paths like `url (.../img/Interface/Icon.svg)`. The templates are then used in a Shopify (slate) theme so all the images need to go straight into the Assets folder, with no sub-folders.

This would be fine as I could just match my static template structure with the Shopify slate theme but apparently the images should be in this format: `#selector {background:url({{ 'image.jpg' | asset_url }});}`.

Can anyone think of a way of managing the CSS when it’s copied across? Manually changing them all the time will be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to write them using the `asset_url` filter.

You can just leave them as `background:url('image.jpg')` and they will work with the only difference that they will be cached this way.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you’re struggling with, but if you want to use liquid in your SCSS file, just save it as `whateverStylesheet.scss.liquid` and then you’ll be able to use any liquid within the file, Shopify processes liquid first and then SCSS before rendering the final CSS document.

Edit: Read [Shopify’s SASS Guide](https://www.shopify.co.uk/partners/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-sass-with-shopify-part-3) for more information.

Comment: The SCSS file is part of a static html template (outside of Shopify) so I don't think it'll recognise the liquid code unfortunately.

Comment: It does, liquid works in CSS, SCSS and JS. But only if their extensions are proceeded with .liquid. Creating a file like: `styles.scss.liquid`, you call it in your main theme file as `styles.css`.

Comment: How would a static SCSS file know what `{{ 'image.jpg' | asset_url }}` is? As there'll be no reference to what an `asset_url` is or how it should render it?

Comment: Shopify processes liquid first and then SCSS. So `{{‘image.jpg | asset_url }}` becomes `cdn.shopify.com/whatever/directory/image.jpg?1847474858`

Comment: I’ve added a link to a guide into my original answer, that’ll show you better how it works.